# Friendly URLs in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My current app is using URLs like:

/philsturgeon
/philsturgeon/trip_slug

I have trips attached to users in my model like so:

```
class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

    def to_param
        "#{user.username}-#{slug}"
    end
end
```

Now I have been told about to_param which seems awesome. It means I can use the normal resource linking:

```
<h4><%= link_to trip.name, trip %></h4>
```

instead of manually creating strings like this:

```
redirect_to('/' + current_user.username + '/' + @trip.slug)
```

Problem is that gives me a hyphen (or dash) separated URL. As soon as I change the URL to_param to `#{user.username}/#{slug}` (notice the slash instead of the dash) I get an error:

> ActionController::RoutingError in
>   Home#index
>
> Showing
>   /Users/phil/Scripts/ruby/travlr/app/views/home/index.html.erb
>   where line #27 raised:
>
> No route matches {:action=>"destroy",
>   :controller=>"trips", :id=>#}
>
> Extracted source (around line #27):
>
> 24:   <%= gravatar trip.user.email, 50
>   %> 25:     26:   27:    <%=
>   link_to trip.name, trip %> 28: 
>   29:    30:
>   **User:**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like hard-coding the URI is the only real solution in this situation. Works fine, but not the nicest code.

Thanks to those who answered, but they weren't quite correct.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `/` to `%2F`. So you should have ...

```
def to_param
    "#{user.username}%2F#{slug}"
end
```

Comment: actually you should escape the whole thing : "#{user.username}-#{slug}".to_s.gsub(/[ ]/, '-')

Comment: That adds the following URL: /trips/philsturgeon%2Famerica-2012 I need to link to /philsturgeon/america-2012

Answer (score -1):

This is happening because '/' has special meaning with reference to URLs. Imagine you have a file in /Home/user/my-file and you try to access it using file://Home/user/my/file

This is basically what you are trying to do. If you want 'file' to be inside 'my' you'll need to store it in there. In the case of Rails you'll need to make a [nested resource](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources).

Comment: Hey, I'm not sure this has anything to do with it as the application sites in the webroot and will always be valid. My URL's currently work fine, I just want to do it the "Rails way".

Comment: You need to add routes to routes.rb to do what you want.

Comment: Yes my route is done, and works fine. I need to link back to that routed page.